# Load different icon set according to theme

Tags: android, layout, icons

I was going to code an application using Holo and Holo light theme and I wanted to know if there is a way to select drawables directly from resources' folder?

For instance, if the loaded theme is Holo, is it possible for the app to choose standard resources (drawable) and go for light version (for instance drawable-light) without having to act programmatically?